# Can Mindstorms EV3 communicate using protocol 802.15.4?

Tags: technic, mindstorms, ev3, programming

My aim is to make the robot communicate using **protocol 802.15.4** through a USB dongle 802.15.4 over 6LoWPAN.

The robot has to be able to get information from TelosB.

I wonder whether this possibility has already been tested and if it is possible to make it work and of course how?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using ev3dev.

https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev/issues/46